# How to read a file from assets folder in a java class without extends Activity class?

Tags: java, android

I would like to read a file under assets folder and then I would like to get the text from my file as return value in Main_Activity class. Here is my code.

**Main.java**

This is the method in the main class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tvRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRes);
    String str = "";
    ReadFile f= new ReadFile();
    try {
        str = f.fileReading();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tvRes.setText(str);
}
}
```

**ReadFile.java**

This *fileReaing()* method is in the ReadFile.java.

```
public String fileReading() throws IOException {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();      
   AssetManager am = getAssets();
    InputStream is = am.open("a.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

After I run this code I found the following error.

```
Process: com.csh.readfile, PID: 4379
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.csh.readfile/com.csh.readfile.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.
Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
```

Please help me to solve this error. I am just beginner of android and thanks to all in advance.

Comment: have you initialized context with "this" keyword oncreate???

Comment: @SnehalGongle , no Sir, I would like to read a file in another java calss and then I would like to get the text from from file as return value. How should i do.

Comment: you can refer the answer bellow by @omar rest i would suggest you to use getApplicationContext() instead of context

Comment: @SnehalGongle, I got it according to the answer of Omar. Thank you so much, Senhal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you did not pass `context` to the `fileReading()` method in `ReadFile.java`, try ,  like below

```
ReadFile f= new ReadFile();
    try {
        str = f.fileReading(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

then

```
public String fileReading(Context c) throws IOException {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();      
   AssetManager am = c.getAssets();
    InputStream is = am.open("a.txt");
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: I got it. This is useful for me. Thank you so much and really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) Pass the context to your method.

```
public String fileReading(Context ctx) throws IOException { 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
 InputStream is = am.open("a.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
String line = null; 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
 sb.append(line + "\n"); 
}
 return sb.toString(); 
}
```

2) Pass the Context to your constructor

```
public class ReadFile{
private Context ctx;

public ReadFile(Context ctx){
this.ctx = ctx:
}

public String fileReading() throws IOException { 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
 InputStream is = am.open("a.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
String line = null; 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
 sb.append(line + "\n"); 
}
 return sb.toString(); 
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for your answer. It also useful for me as another way . Really thank you.

Comment: If it helps, consider accepting answer or voting up.